# Como imprimir formulário actual em MS Access?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Através dum botão de comando, desejo imprimir, numa base de dados, o formulário actual no MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Comando0_Click()

    DoCmd.PrintOut

End Sub
```

Este método aceita os seguintes parâmetros (depois de `printout`):

- PrintRange
- PageFrom
- PageTo
- PrintQuality
- Copies
- CollateCopies

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192667.aspx